# DataBound ComboBox not changing when an item is selected

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataBound ComboBox and everything on it works great. But when I select an item in the list, the SelectedValue changes correctly but the text that gets displayed stays on the first item.

There is no code behind this, I added the DataBinding in the form builder.

Answer (score 0):

It was a dumb mistake. 
I had the SelectedValue set in the DataBinding Menu.